# Linearly independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have two vectors groups  $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_s,\alpha_{s+1}$ and $\beta_i=\alpha_i+t_i\alpha_{s+1},\ i=1,2,\cdots,s$. Prove that if $\beta_1,\cdots,\beta_s$ are linearly independent, then $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_s,\alpha_{s+1}$ are also.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in particular $\alpha_{s+1} = \frac{\beta_{s+1}}{1+t_{s+1}}$ so that

$a_{1}\alpha_{1} + ... + a_{s+1}\alpha_{s+1} = 0$ implies

$a_{1}\left(\beta_{1}-t_{1}\frac{\beta_{s+1}}{1+t_{s+1}}\right) + ... + a_{s+1}\frac{\beta_{s+1}}{1+t_{s+1}} = 0$

Group vectors and factor so that you exhibit the coefficients.  Since this is a linear combination of independent vectors, these coefficients must be all 0.  Use this to infer that $a_{1} = a_{2} = ... = a_{s+1} = 0$.

Comment: Here, we do not have $\beta_{s+1}$, but only $\beta_1,\cdots,\beta_s$.

Comment: I see.  Then use the fact that $\beta_{s+1}$ is a linear combination of $\{\beta_{i}\}_{i=1,...,s}$ to substitute and then you have a linear combination of linearly independent vectors and the proof goes basically the same.

Comment: But then, you could not represent $\alpha_{s+1}$ as you did.

Comment: You can if you first represent it that way, and then after that, do the switch $\beta_{s+1}$ with its representation in terms of the basis vectors.

Comment: I still could not get the idea...